# (qt/embedded) How to load a library before running the program

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

Good morning. Everyone.

I am working with qt 4.8. (Embedded linux)
The server application is executing the client application using qprocess(). At this point, the client application is slow to load, so the system appears to be paused when the user sees it.

I think the reason for the slowness is the time to load the external library into memory. So I wonder if there is a way to pre-load the library to be used by the client application when the server application goes through the init process.

Please let me know if there is a better way. Thank you.

Comment: You can try to load it in the first program using QLibraby. Not sure if this is the best way.

Comment: @DragosPop QLibrary loads a shared library into the current process, so that won't help here.

Comment: I know, it might help by making the so cache the library. Anyway I found a batter solution. See my answere.

Answer (score 1):

Since the other application will have to load its own libraries on startup this is not an easy task, but you could get around the slow loading by preparing the desired application and its libraries to be loaded from ramdisk instead of loading from hard-disk.

In Main Application create a RAM disk using mount

```
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=200M none /mnt/ramdisk
```

copy all required files over and set up `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as an environment to point to your ramdisk (Qt)

```
auto env = QProcess::systemEnvironment();
env.insert("LD_LIBRARY_PATH","/mnt/ramdisk");
```

Set the new environment to be your environment for your QProcess. As I am not 100% sure this will load your library from there, as an alternative you could create a `chroot` environment and setup libraries in `/usr/lib` in the chroot environment.

The idea is to get the library and application loaded from RAM into RAM, which is much faster than loading from disk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought it was a good idea. I did the testing in this way. I moved the qt libs needed for qt app execution to ramdisk. The speed of execution of the A app has been dramatically improved. However, the execution speed of B app executed using QProcess() in A app is the same.

Comment: If you `strace` your application for open file descriptors, you probably will see the app still tryling to load the library from disk instead of RAMdisk. Thats the shared library concept of linux and its search and load priority path. Check for the `ld.so.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Preload and prelink might help. Never used them but found some documentation to start: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Preload